# Progress bar for counting checkboxes

Tags: java, android, checkbox, progress-bar

I need every click on the checkbox to increase the percentage in progressBar.

Example: I have two checkboxes, each corresponding to 50% within the progressBar.

I tried several codes, but none worked, I'm a beginner in java

Can someone help me? Please.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        final CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);         

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        if (preferences.contains("checkbox1") && preferences.getBoolean("checkbox1", false) == true) {
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    editor.putBoolean("checkbox1", true);
                    editor.apply();
                } else {
                    editor.putBoolean("checkbox1", false);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            }
        });

        if (preferences.contains("checkbox2") && preferences.getBoolean("checkbox2", false) == true) {
            checkBox2.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            checkBox2.setChecked(false);
        }

        checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (checkBox2.isChecked()) {
                    editor.putBoolean("checkbox2", true);
                    editor.apply();
                } else {
                    editor.putBoolean("checkbox2", false);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Add progressBar.setProgress(value); inside setOnCheckedChangeListener

Comment: You have not done anything with your `ProgressBar` so far? Currently you only store what checkbox was taped in SharedPreferences.

Comment: so simple, it worked lol  
thank you @IshanFernando

Comment: I got it, thank you. @H.Brooks